# what is the non-standard words&usage in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql for a while. I think to switch pdo, and want to use standard function. Can you provide non-standard syntax in mysql?

First think `LIMIT` in oracle they use rowcount, and mssql they use TOP .

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement has quite a lot of differences across systems.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the question you are looking for:

[There are a method to paging using ANSI SQL only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463859/there-are-a-method-to-paging-using-ansi-sql-only)

Comment: The question seems to be more general than merely about the particular syntax differences for paging. The `LIMIT` part is likely just an example.