# How to use LIMIT [X] OFFSET [Y] with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)

How to use LIMIT [X] OFFSET [Y] with SQL Server 2005, i see mysql, oracle, sqllite, postgre have it, microsoft dont realize we need it ?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft (for a change, you might say) chose to implement the ANSI standard instead of coming up with their own proprietary keyword like LIMIT. In the next version of SQL Server (code-named "Denali") you will be able to use [OFFSET / FETCH](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/10/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-the-offset-clause-paging) (also see [this post on simulating keyset](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)).

In the meantime, you will need to use different methods with SQL Server (or switch platforms if you think that is easier than extra typing). A good article about a few methods for paging in existing versions is here:

- [SQL Server 2005 Paging – The Holy Grail](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/)

Be sure to click on "Join the Discussion" to read over the 60+ follow-up comments that discuss various aspects of the solutions provided.

Note that OFFSET / FETCH is not implemented for performance reasons; only for productivity. In other words, OFFSET / FETCH will perform about the same as the ROW_NUMBER() solutions typically in use today.

**EDIT** While some have demonstrated cases where Denali performs better on the first page (e.g. [this one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2420/sql-server-2012-server-side-paging/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)), this is not the intention, and I'm not convinced the delta remains true as you traverse the table and get to the latter pages (particularly on large tables).