# how to implement Pagination in hibernate, while using Session.createSQLQuery(SQL_Query) method

Tags: hibernate, pagination

I'm trying to implement pagination in Hibernate for a native Sql Query. I am using `Query query = Session.createSQlQuery(Sql_Query);` for executing query. How can I implement/add pagination in it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no default method for it, if you are using native sql then use `limit` and `offset` in your query to achieve the same.

---

### EDIT 1

For your query in comment:

I'm not very much familiar with MS SQL but I found this pages that can help you to kick off:

- [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)
- [How to use LIMIT [X] OFFSET [Y] with SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598176/how-to-use-limit-x-offset-y-with-sql-server-2005)
- For more search on net.... :)

Comment: Hey Harry,Thanks for the quick reply...

I am new to MS SQL Database. so, Can u help me how to achieve this in MS Sql Server 2008 version ?