# How to implement paging mechanism in generic way for SQL standards?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, db2

In a project, we have successfully implemented the paging mechanism for SQL Server, but as per our requirement, we are trying to implement the paging mechanism in generic way for Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 & DB400 databases. Is it possible to implement paging in such way?  What can be the simplest generic way to implement such query?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463859/there-are-a-method-to-paging-using-ansi-sql-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no generic functionality to implement the pagining mechanism for the all the database.

The syntax to implement the pagination may also change with the database, so it is hard to say that there is a genric functionality to implement it across all the database.

You can refer [There are a method to paging using ANSI Sql only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463859/there-are-a-method-to-paging-using-ansi-sql-only) where the accepted answer refers to a [link](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit-offset) which says to use it like

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY key ASC) AS rownum,
    columns
  FROM tablename
) AS foo
WHERE rownum > skip AND rownum <= (n+skip)
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, Does Oracle,DB2,DB400 support CTE syntax i.e. Common Table Expression ?

Comment: @MaximusDecimusMeridius:- Yes you can use it. For Oracle you can refer this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/921467?tstart=0

Comment: Thank you,MS-SQL server,Oracle,DB2,DB400 supports CTE, that means the paging can be implemented using few of the mathematical calculations. Atleast we can create generic query for these 4 databases,Am i correct ?

Comment: @MaximusDecimusMeridius:- Yes, with few calculations it can be done!

Comment: Thanks Rahul,i will get back to you in case of difficulties.

Comment: @MaximusDecimusMeridius:- You are welcome! Surely, I will wait!

Comment: I have the scenario like,while moving back & forth to display the records as per the row numbers per page there is possibility that new set of records might have been added in the database & the page number we are sending might fail, so will it work to display the data properly in paging ?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand. Try this:

```
WITH MyCte AS 
(
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY FieldName) ID, *  FROM TableName
)
SELECT  *
FROM    MyCte
WHERE   ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: Will it be okay with Oracle,DB2,DB400 ? I mean the syntax provided by you ?

Comment: I am not sure about oracle. Might some functions not available with same name like CTE, Row_Number. But the logic should be same. You need to check the functions equivalent in Oracle. If CTE not available yo can use sub query. Inner Select statement Add Serial Number and from Outer Select statement you can put check according to the page number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, there are multiple ways:

- **ROWNUM** in subquery and **ORDER BY** in outer query
- Analytic **ROW_NUMBER()**
- **TOP-n row limiting clause** in new Oracle 12c

Using **ROWNUM:**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT level col
  3  FROM   dual
  4  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
  5  )
  6  SELECT col
  7  FROM   (SELECT col, rownum AS rnum
  8          FROM   (SELECT col
  9                  FROM   data
 10                  ORDER BY col)
 11          WHERE rownum <= 8)
 12  WHERE  rnum >= 5;

       COL
----------
         5
         6
         7
         8
```

Using Analytic **ROW_NUMBER()**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT level col
  3  FROM   dual
  4  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
  5  )
  6  SELECT * FROM (
  7    SELECT
  8      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) rn
  9    FROM DATA
 10  )
 11  WHERE rn >= 5 AND rn <= 8;

        RN
----------
         5
         6
         7
         8
```

Using **Top-n row limiting clause**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT level col
  3  FROM   dual
  4  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
  5  )
  6  SELECT col
  7  FROM   DATA
  8  ORDER BY col
  9  OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;

       COL
----------
         5
         6
         7
         8
```